# How to compare values from a google sheets column to an array and send to specific emails based on column data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm automating my google sheets to send out emails automatically and I can't figure out how to compare a variable array to a column in my google sheets. I keep getting all values returned rather than just the ones in my array when I put it in an 'IF' statement.
I want my code to only show data that is in my gEnglish variable but instead shows me all data. I was also wondering how I'd be able to send emails based on regions to users.

```
    function sendEmails() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Main").activate();
    
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var lr = ss.getLastRow();
    
    var decisionOne = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Templates").getRange(1,1).getValue();
    var decisionTWO = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Templates").getRange(2,1).getValue();
    var decisionThree = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Templates").getRange(3,1).getValue();
    var decisionFour = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Templates").getRange(5,1).getValue();
    var decisionFive = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Templates").getRange(4,1).getValue();
    
    var gEnglish = ["IT","US","GB","UK"];
    var gSpanish = ["SP"];
    
    var user1 = ["JP","SK","IND","RU"];
    var user2 = [gEnglish,"UK"];
    var user3 = [gSpanish, "BR", "PT"];
    var user4 = ["FR", "DE","IT"];
    
    for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++){
      var type = ss.getRange(i,6).getValue();
      var region = ss.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
      var decision = ss.getRange(i,15).getValue();
        //I used to have if(region == gEnglish)
        if(gEnglish.includes(region[i]) ){
      var channel = ss.getRange(i,3).getValue();
      var decision = ss.getRange(i,15).getValue();
      var url = ss.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
      var name = ss.getRange(i,11).getValue();
      var messageBody = {};
      var subjectLine = "blahblahblah";
    }
    
    
    }
    }
```

If my array only has one value inside it works fine but as soon as I put more I just get all values returned.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am feeling that this is not the only thing you are doing wrong. For starters, `var=i` does not exist in JavaScript. Please change the for loop to: `for(var i=0;i<=lastRow;i++)`. Secondly, **assuming** `persons` is an `1D` array then you could do `if(coolPeople.includes(persons[i]))`. But I am pretty sure that `persons` is a 2D array and you are messing with the data structures. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64504171/edit) your question to include the full code.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a column into a flat array.

```
function col2array() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vA=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().flat();
}
```

In Google Apps Script a column looks like:

`[[Row1],[Row2],[Row3],[Row4]....]`

```
function lookingforarrayvaluesinacolumn() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vA=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  const coolpeople = ["p1","p2"];
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(coolpeople.indexOf(r[0])!=-1) {
      //the r[0] is a cool person
    }
  });
}
```